# Transferring data from textbox to 2D Array

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my C# project.

Suppose I have a textbox1 as follow (n rows x n columns):

```
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now I want to transfer data from this text box into an existed 2d Matrix that will store data in Integer Type.

I tried this but it seem to not works:

```
private void GETNUMERICDATA()
{
    string txt = textbox1.text;
    txt = txt.Replace(" ", string.Empty);   
    for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < 32; l++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
            {
                char chr = txt[i];
                if (chr == '0')
                {
                    Matrix[k, l] = (int)char.GetNumericValue('0');
                }
                else
                {
                    if (chr == '1')
                    Matrix[k, l] = (int)char.GetNumericValue('1');                             
                }
            }    
        }
    }           
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: is there spaces between 0 and 1?

Comment: how doesn't it work? it seems ok!

Comment: `(int)char.GetNumericValue('0')` is a lot easier to understand written as `0`.

Comment: By the way you can make the code shorter for example `if (chr == '0') Matrix[k, l] = 0; ...`

Comment: What should this method exactly do? Fill the array as long as there are input values (so if there are 60 input values, 60 array items are filled) or are there 1024 input values all the time, so the whole array can be filled?

Comment: Hi Thomas Lielacher, I would like to get the 32x32 matrix, which contains just 0 and 1. I had tried your code below but the result matrix contains only 0 value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the third loop over the input. You loop through the whole input every time. The result is, that after all loops have finished, the array will contain only the last value of your input. Try this:

```
private void GETNUMERICDATA()
{
    int currentPosition = 0;
    string txt = textbox1.text;
    txt = txt.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

    for (int k = 0; k < 32 && currentPosition < txt.Length; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < 32 && currentPosition < txt.Length; l++)
        {
            char chr = txt[currentPosition];

            if (chr == '0')
            {
                Matrix[k, l] = (int)char.GetNumericValue('0');
            }
            else if (chr == '1')
            {
                Matrix[k, l] = (int)char.GetNumericValue('1');
            }

            currentPosition++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas Lielacher,

Thanks for you quick answer, I tried this code but it didn't work.

Comment: The result matrix is: (n rows (0) x n columns(0).

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. Just modify in txt;

```
private void GETNUMERICDATA()
{
    int currentPosition = 0;
    string txt = textbox1.text;
    txt = txt.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    txt = txt.Replace(Environment.Newline, string.Empty);
    //Just add this code line

    for (int k = 0; k < 32 && currentPosition < txt.Length; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < 32 && currentPosition < txt.Length; l++)
        {
            char chr = txt[currentPosition];

            if (chr == '0')
            {
                Matrix[k, l] = 0;
            }
            else if (chr == '1')
            {
                Matrix[k, l] = 1;
            }

            currentPosition++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks all for your helping! Have a nice day.